# Is it possible for kotlin to call jvm11 code? How?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

Kotlin generates jvm8 or jvm6 code. Consider the following:

- You write a jvm11 (in java) library
- You write a kotlin app that wishes to consume the jvm11 library

Is this possible? If so how does this work under the hood?

Comment: This seems to work when I try it. But given I don't understand the underlying mechanism, I'm nervous there may be failure cases.

Comment: If your Kotlin app is compiled to JVM 8 bytecode, then it will run on a JVM 11 too. On the other hand, if your kotlin app depends on a Java 11 library, it will not run under any JVMs below 11. There's nothing magic happening under the hood, JVMs are just backwards compatible, meaning newer JVMs accept older bytecode, but older JVMs may not accept newer bytecode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the way JVM works and isn't specific to Kotlin at all.

Let's say you have two classes `Class1` and `Class2`, and `Class1` needs to call `Class2`. Then `Class1`'s bytecode only uses `Class2`'s name and signatures of its members. It doesn't know or care if `Class2` was compiled for Java 5, Java 11, or Java 5000.

The `Class1` bytecode says e.g. "call this `Class2` constructor with these arguments". When this code is executed, `Class2` is loaded (if it wasn't already) and its bytecode version is compared with the one JVM understands.

Comment: So there is no way to use JVM11 specific features in a method or class signature?

Comment: I don't think there _are_ any JVM11 features in method signatures to use in the first place :) You can use types and methods added to the standard library.

Comment: According https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/9jpdn1/are_there_any_plans_to_support_java_11_byte_code/, Kotlin will eventually get JVM11 bytecode support, but that shouldn't affect compatibility with any libraries, your classes will just fail to load if you try to use them on older JVMs.